# Benefits of IComparable<T> as Contravariant?

Tags: c#, contravariance, icomparable

I have very little experience with variance, but after having read quite a bit believe that I understand at least the basic concepts (i.e. variance describes the relationship between the relationship of two types and the relationship of those two types similarly projected). However, I can't seem to grasp the significance or benefits of having `IComparable<T>` defined as contravariant. At first glance, this actually appears to hinder comparability between subtypes. I'm hopeful that someone might be able to shed some light on the matter.

Answer (score 7):

I'll tackle `IComparer<T>` first - it's not mentioned in your question, but it's a slightly easier "sell" that then leads to `IComparable<T>`.

Suppose you have three classes:

- Shape (has an Area property)
- Circle : Shape
- Square : Shape

It's easy to write an `AreaComparer : IComparer<Shape>`.

Contravariance allows you to sort a `List<Circle>` by area, because an `IComparer<Shape>` (such as `AreaComparer`) is convertible to `IComparer<Circle>`.

Likewise for `IComparable<T>` - if `Shape` itself declared itself to be `IComparable<Shape>` using `Area`, then again you could sort a `List<Circle>` because each circle would be comparable to itself as a shape.

Now a lot of the time this wouldn't actually be a problem, because you'd have the implicit conversion from `Circle` to `Shape`. But the natural ability for a `Circle` to be regarded as an `IComparable<Circle>` could help in terms of type inference for generic methods. For example, suppose we have:

```
void Foo<T>(IComparable<T> item1, T item2)
```

And we try to call

```
Foo(circle1, circle2);
```

I don't know offhand whether the compiler would (without contravariance) be able to infer `T=Shape`, which would work... but even if it could, it would fail for:

```
void Foo<T>(IComparable<T> item1, T item2) where T : ISomethingCircleImplements
```

Really we want the compiler to be happy with `T=Circle`, I'd suggest - which is only valid if a `Circle` is an `IComparable<Circle>` via covariance.

EDIT: Here's an example of it working:

```
using System;

public abstract class Shape : IComparable<Shape>
{
    public abstract double Area { get; }

    public int CompareTo(Shape other)
    {
        return Area.CompareTo(other.Area);
    }
}

public interface ISomethingCircleImplements {}

public class Circle : Shape, ISomethingCircleImplements
{
    private readonly double radius;

    public Circle(double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public override double Area { get { return radius * radius * Math.PI; } }
}

class Test
{
    static void Foo<T>(IComparable<T> item1, T item2)
        where T : ISomethingCircleImplements
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item1.CompareTo(item2));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(10);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(20);

        Foo<Circle>(c1, c2);
    }
}
```

Interestingly, type inference *doesn't* work here - but I'm not sure why. The contravariance itself is fine though.

Comment: Jon, having now read through your response multiple times I think this is actually beginning to make some sense. Thanks!

Comment: Jon, it appears as though I prematurely accepted your answer. Still finding myself with questions, I took some time to implement a test case involving the proposed Foo<T> example. It doesn't compile with error, "The type 'Testable.Shape' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Testable.Test.Foo<T>(System.IComparable<T>, T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Testable.Shape' to 'Testable.ISomethingCircleImplements'"

Comment: @blf: Right, but you don't want T=Shape there. You want T=Circle, which is only valid if Circle implements `IComparable<Circle>`, which it only does through contravariance.

Comment: Jon, I see. I misunderstood. I'll have to give it a bit more thought, but won't have the time to run more tests until later this afternoon. Perhaps I'm merely misunderstanding once again, however I have an idea that this might not work either. Consider a class Shape which implements IShape and IComparer<Shape> and also consider a List<IShape> containing Shapes. Then calling List<IShape>.Sort() results in calls to IComparer rather than IComparer<Shape> (which seems rather unfortunate). Nevertheless, thanks for the feedback! It's sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Jon, okay, I had some more free time than I thought so I gave the tests a run. Turns out that the compiler, as you suggested, is able to determine T=Circle when given the Foo<T> method. I find it quite strange that it is not able to do the same with List<T>. I'm going to go ahead an mark this as accepted. I am wondering, however, if you have any ideas why Sort() isn't able to make the same inferences? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @blf: Probably worth asking a separate question about that with full code.

Comment: Jon, I will certainly do so! :)

Comment: Jon, based on the response I receive in the other question, I'm now reconsidering this example in different light. Perhaps the Foo<T> example doesn't demonstrate contravariance at all? Since the where clause is a restriction rather than a required type and I've passed in two circles, then of course calling CompareTo on the circle will result in CompareTo(circle) being called because it is the best match. Does this make sense?

Comment: @blf: It demonstrates contravariance when you call it with `Circle` - because it requires that `Circle` implements `IComparable<Circle>`, when the only explicit declaration is that `Shape` implements `IComparable<Shape>`. Without contravariance, the call wouldn't compile.

Comment: Jon, I really hate to be a bother, but interestingly enough this is not compiling unless circle implements its own IComparable<Circle>. I can post a test case if you would like to see. This is being compiled with compiler version 4.0.30319.1.

Comment: @blf: Rather than continuing this very long comment thread, I'd suggest you put that into a new question.

Comment: @blf: I've edited my code to show it working, albeit without type inference for `T`. I'm not sure why that's not working offhand, but when you specify `T=Circle` it's fine.